# How to get Customer custom attribute Label

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I've created some custom attributes for customers. I can retrieve the values normally using `$customer->getData('attribute')`. But i also need the label for the respective attribute, the frontend label. I know there are a lot of answers out there, i did searched, but all of those answers is related with products, i want the customer custom attributes.

One of those answers i've tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12469321/4687714
but it return the value formated to frontend store, i want the attribute **label**.

So, how do i return the **Label** of a Customer custom attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
 $attributeLabel = $customer->getResource()
                 ->getAttribute('attribute_name')
                 ->getFrontend()
                 ->getAttribute()
                 ->getFrontendLabel();
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can use short version. It should be work also. 

$customer->getResource()
->getAttribute('attribute_name')
->getFrontendLabel();

Comment: how to get its value what we filled for particular customer ?